# Apex class access issue with profile : summer 22 release

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, profile, summer-22

We are facing many issue related to apex class access across multiple profile. This issue started just after summer22 release patch. Our org is impacted and many users with different profile are complaining that they are getting error message while accessing some component. In error msg it shows that you dont have apex class access. And when we are adding those apex class in their profile access, issue is gone. But I want to know where this issue coming from? I am not sure if any recent update has created this issue.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Is this related to custom or standard profile assigned to users ? we had this issue too on a sandbox after summer 22 release with standard profiles. It seems that after summer 22 release some std profiles were "updated" and apex class access were removed. so we cloned the standard profiles and used custom ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, why it is happening to you only now because in **Winter '21** there is release enforcement which has been enforced. [Restrict Access to @AuraEnabled Apex Methods for Authenticated Users Based on User Profile (Update, Enforced)](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lc_restrict_apex_authenticated_users.htm&type=5&release=228)

As a part of this release, the user which is invoking `@AuraEnabled` apex method (aura, or LWC) should have access to the class, that contains this method.

> When this update is enforced, an authenticated user can access an
> @AuraEnabled Apex method only when the user’s profile allows access to
> the Apex class. This update is enforced in Winter ’21.

Comment: Yes I notice the same, all apex classes have this annotation. But need to understand more. If we are explicitly providing these apex class access to some Guest user profile, which might not result in some security issue. But as of now for licensed user, we are providing class access from profile.